# T-SQL convert a string to geometry data type

Tags: sql, geometry, convert, geometry-conversion

I want to convert a string to geometry data type using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN geometrie TYPE geometry(Point) USING st_astext(geometrie);
```

I get error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'geometry'.
```

The column has values like this: `010100002040710000CDCCCCCCEC94FB403D0AD7A33FC91D41`

Comment: Those values *might* be WKB (Well Known Binary) format.  Have a look at the function STGeomFromWKB()

Comment: Focusing only on the sytax error, SQL Server geometry and geography data types have no [Precision, scale, and length (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), so `geometry(point)` is throwing the syntax error.  I suspect correcting this syntax error will lead to the next error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe would be less problematic for you to create a new column in your table with geometry type and then insert the values of 'geometrie' as points on your new column

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET new_geometrie= ST_GeomFromWKB(geometrie::geometry)
WHERE new_geometrie IS NULL
```

[image: example]